# How to return an answer to a textarea?

Tags: javascript

I've just just recently begun to learn how to write Javascript, started a few weeks ago. Right now I'm working on making an interactive story. The way I've been planning on making the story is having the user answer a prompt question, and the answer to the prompt will trigger the next part of the story to be shown in a textbox.

So as of now, I have my prompts down and the if/else statements that will reveal the answer. I can't figure out how to make the next part of the story show up in the textbox.

The only thing I can really think of right now is using console.log, but that won't work quite right. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: You can set the `value` attribute of the DOM element.

Comment: Post some code, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that there is no code to reference, here's a mock-up example:

```
document.getElementById("myTextArea").value = prompt("Foo?");
```

Assuming you would have a textarea like this

```
<textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>
```

its text would then be set to whatever the user entered, for instance,

```
bar
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XuwUK/3/)

Comment: This seems to have done the trick

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is putting story information in the `textarea` then you shouldn't be using it, just use a `div` instead and put the story text in there.  Have the div initially set to `display: none` and once they get the question right, set it to `display: block` using JS!